# images precompiled, heroku keeps complaining on some

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment, precompiled

I added an image to the /app/assets/images folder, logo-small.jpg

Then I added this line to my view

```
= link_to image_tag('logo-small.jpg'), root_path, :class => 'brand'
```

Then I precompiled,

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

git add, git commit and git push heroku master. the push works.

I'm still getting the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (logo-small.jpg isn't precompiled):
```

why?

EDIT: I've tried other images, they're fine. Heroku has an issue with logo and logo-small, but not with other images. wtf??

Comment: what stack are you running on heroku? the new Cedar stack should automatically precompile your assets. if it's older you may have to run a rake task on the server.

Comment: Cedar. I opened my account 2 days ago.

Comment: thanks. can you manually run the `assets:precompile` on your server like below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never found out what it was. switched the format from jpg to png and it worked.

Comment: Always use png unless it's a photo

Comment: Pngs are lossless. Josh's are lossy. Photos are a good thing for lossy. Tab images should use lossless

Answer (score 1):

If you are on heroku's Cedar stack, your assets should be automatically precompiled when you push to heroku. If you're on that stack and still getting errors, that would be good to know.

If you're on the Bamboo stack (which is a little bit older but used to be the default), you can try running a [rake task](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake) on the server to have it compile the assets that you've already pushed.

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: i did. still the same result.